# ionic 3 file uploading from filechooser to firebase storage

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload a pdf from ionic 3 app to firebase.
by using this method I can upload a text file by just creating them.`

```
uploadToStorage(information):AngularFireUploadTask
  {
    let newName = `${new Date().getTime()}.txt`;
    return this.afST.ref(`files/${newName}`).putString(information);

  }`
```

here is the place where i call the function

```
uploadInfo(text)
  {
    let upload = this.dataProvider.uploadToStorage(text);

    upload.then(res=>{
      console.log('res',res);
      this.dataProvider.storeInfoOnDatabase(res.metadata,text).then(()=>{
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message : 'New File Added',
          duration: 3000
        });
        toast.present();
      });
    });
  }
```

what i need to do is how i expand the `uploadstorage()` function to upload a file getting from ionic file chooser

Answer (score 0):

Include FirebaseApp in your constructor

Then use following code (Change according to your scenario. Following is the code to upload an image)

```
const pic = this.firebaseApp.storage().ref(path/filename.png);
pic.putString(selectedPicture, 'base64', {contentType: 'image/png'})
    .then((savedImage) => {
        console.log(savedImage);
    });
```